# How To Chain SSH Tunnels

Tags: networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to set up a simple SSH tunnels chain.

I have the following machines:

1. local machine, at 10.0.0.1.
2. remote machine, at 10.0.0.2.

I have the following programs:

1. client.py:

   ```
   import socket

   CLIENT_HOST = [...]
   CLIENT_PORT = [...]

   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
   sock.connect((CLIENT_HOST, CLIENT_PORT))
   sock.send('test')
   sock.close()
   ```
2. server.py:

   ```
   import socket

   SERVER_HOST = [...]
   SERVER_PORT = [...]

   server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
   server.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
   server.listen(1)
   client = server.accept()[0]
   print client.recv(1024)
   client.close()
   server.close()
   ```

Now:

1. I run client.py (CLIENT_HOST='127.0.0.1', CLIENT_PORT=8000) and server.py (SERVER_HOST='', SERVER_PORT=8000) on the same machine, and it works as expected.
2. I run client.py (CLIENT_HOST='127.0.0.1', CLIENT_PORT=8000) on the local machine, and server.py (SERVER_HOST='', SERVER_PORT=8001) on the remote machine. I then run PuTTY and add a local SSH tunnel with the source port 8000 and the destination 10.0.0.2:8001, and it works as expected.
3. I run client.py (CLIENT_HOST='127.0.0.1', CLIENT_PORT=8001) on the remote machine, and server.py (SERVER_HOST='', SERVER_PORT=8002) on the local machine. I then run PuTTY and add a remote SSH tunnel with the source port 8001 and the destination 127.0.0.1:8002, and it works as expected.
4. However, when I run client.py (CLIENT_HOST='127.0.0.1', CLIENT_PORT=8000) and server.py (SERVER_HOST='', SERVER_PORT=8002) on the local machine, and run two PuTTYs, one with a local SSH tunnel from source port 8000 to destination 10.0.0.2:8001, and one with a remote SSH tunnel from source port 8001 to destination 127.0.0.1:8002, nothing happens.

As I see it, the message from client.py should be sent to the local machine's port 8000, where PuTTY listens and should redirect it via SSH to the remote machine's port 8001, where a PuTTY listens and should redirect it via SSH to the local machine's port 8002, where it should reach server.py.

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to tick 'Local ports accept connections from other hosts' and 'Remote ports do the same'.

By the way, `netcat` is a more useful standard utility for trying this kind of thing out, if it's available on your OS.